# TikZ: Line with large dots

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a simple way to draw a line like with `\draw[dotted] (0,0) -- (1,0);` but with larger (radius about 1mm) and more distant (about 4mm) dots?

I've looked in the [TikZ & PGF manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), section "15.3.2 Graphic Parameters: Dash Pattern" but found nothing useful.

My workaround is using a `\foreach` and drawing `circle` nodes.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use a `decoration`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={markings,
  mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 6pt
  with { \draw [fill] (0,0) circle [radius=2pt];}}]
\path[postaction={decorate}] (0,0) to (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or using `decorations.shapes`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{decorate sep/.style 2 args=
{decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=circle,shape size=#1,shape sep=#2}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[decorate sep={2mm}{4mm},fill] (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[decorate sep={2mm}{6mm},fill] (0,1) -- (4,1);
\draw[decorate sep={1mm}{4mm},fill] (0,2) -- (4,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! I like your second solution more, it looks cleaner…

Answer (score 24):

It's possible with simple options. Logically with `dotted`,  you get only squares or rectangles.

For example :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{dotted}= [dash pattern=on \pgflinewidth off 4mm]  
\draw[dotted,line width = 2mm] (0,0) -- (5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

A strange idea is to use `line cap=round` to get circles instead squares. A pattern is a rectangle but with  `line cap=round` you get a ice rink and if you reduce the width enough, you get circles. The method is funny.

**update**  I added a style

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circle dotted/.style={dash pattern=on .05mm off 8mm,
                                         line cap=round}]
  \draw[line width = 2mm,circle dotted] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is indeed a funny solution, thanks :-)