# How to reduce distance between branch and cdots

Tags: tikz-pgf

I create a tree by node/child as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{nodestyle} = [circle,draw,minimum size=5pt]

    \node [nodestyle, inner sep=0pt] {$\{X\}|_{\aleph_0}$}
    child {node {$\vdots$}
        child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=4pt] (a) {$X$}}
    }; 
    \path (0,0.7) node[above] {$X,X_1,X_2\in\mathcal{E}$};

    \begin{scope}[xshift=2.7cm]
    \node [nodestyle, inner sep=0pt] {$\{S\}|_{\aleph_0}$}
    child {node {$\vdots$}
        child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=3pt] (a) {$S$}
                child {node [nodestyle,inner sep=0pt] {$\{X_1\}$}
                    child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=1pt] {$X_1$}}
                }
                child {node [nodestyle,inner sep=1pt] (e) {$X_2$}}          
        }
    }; 

    \path (0,0.7) node[above] {$S=\{\{X_1\},X_2\}$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to set distance from branch above cdots to be same as that of below cdots. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use nodes for this, you may want to have a look at this snippet. (I also updated tikzstyle to tikzset.)

**UPDATE**: You are right. I actually never realized that dotted does not really produce dots.

**SECOND UPDATE**: I hope I understand your request correctly. Now the dots start 1mm below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes,calc}
\begin{document}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52849/121799
\tikzset{decorate sep/.style 2 args=
{decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=circle,shape size=#1,shape sep=#2}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{nodestyle/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=5pt}} % changed

    \node [nodestyle, inner sep=0pt] {$\{X\}|_{\aleph_0}$}
    child {node[minimum size=1cm] (dummy1) {}
        child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=4pt] (a) {$X$}}
    }; 
    \draw[decorate sep={0.4mm}{2mm},fill] ($(dummy1.north)-(0,1mm)$) -- (dummy1.south);
    \path (0,0.7) node[above] {$X,X_1,X_2\in\mathcal{E}$};

    \begin{scope}[xshift=2.7cm]
    \node [nodestyle, inner sep=0pt] {$\{S\}|_{\aleph_0}$}
    child {node[minimum size=1cm] (dummy2) {}
        child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=3pt] (a) {$S$}
                child {node [nodestyle,inner sep=0pt] {$\{X_1\}$}
                    child {node [nodestyle, inner sep=1pt] {$X_1$}}
                }
                child {node [nodestyle,inner sep=1pt] (e) {$X_2$}}          
        }
    }; 
    \draw[decorate sep={0.4mm}{2mm},fill] ($(dummy2.north)-(0,1mm)$) -- (dummy2.south);
    \path (0,0.7) node[above] {$S=\{\{X_1\},X_2\}$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is good, but there are 2 problems. First is there way to change dot to round (currently is square)? Second can number of dots be reduced to 4 or 5?

Comment: @MathWizard Sorry, I don't understand your first comment, but perhaps you are using a viewer that lets the dots appear as squares? (Just zoom in to check.) And for point 2: Very simple: either decrease  in `minimum size=1cm` to `1cm` to some smaller value and/or play with the line style, e.g. `loosely dotted` instead of `dotted`.

Comment: First question means that dots are square (I change line style to very thick and you can see when zoom), while dots in \cdots are circle.

Comment: @MathWizard Apologies! You're right, please see my update.

Comment: @ marmot, thanks for the answer. Last question, is it possible for dot not to start at the end of branch of node? The reason is that I have other tree with more children that is connected by cdots, which I will not change to dummy variable.

Comment: @MathWizard I hope that I understood your question correctly. Please see the update.