# Limitations of TikZ Braids: Are there alternatives?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, braids

I've been using the Tikz `braids` package which is all nice and great, but it's also limiting in that there seems to be only one way to generate braids. For example, I think a lot of people like to draw braids like this (apologies for the blurriness; was trying to avoid an oversized image):

[image]

(This is from Fresse's *Homotopy of Operads*.)
However, the `braids` package is designed to show you, **one at a time**, the action of **every single generator**. This is great for pedagogy! But complicated braids have lots of generators. As a result, complex braids get really long. For example, I hand drew the braid on the left. Plugging it into the `braids` package, I get the picture on the right

[image][image]

**Issues.**

My issue is that (1) the braid doesn't fit on a single page.
Now I can use `adjustbox` to scale it to make it fit, but this brings my second issue: it makes the braid look more complicated than it really needs to be.

**Questions.**

So my questions are: **Is this really all that the TikZ `braids` package can do?** I looked at the documentation and it seems to be the case. In addition, **are there other alternatives to generating braids in TikZ? How are other authors (e.g. Fresse above) generating their braids?** Are they really just hardcoding a tikzpicture every time?

Also, there's [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413455/pure-braid-generators-with-vertical-strands) but this just looks like a nightmare to do in general. In my experience with TikZ it often requires way too much time to just generate something pretty
simple, so I don't want to hard code it (if I can avoid it!!).

Finally, I don't know if it helps, but heres my code for the above braid.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\braid[number of strands= 9, thick,
style strands={1}{red},
style strands={2}{red},
style strands={3}{red},
style strands={4}{Green},
style strands={5}{Green},
style strands={6}{Black},
style strands={7}{RoyalBlue},
style strands={8}{RoyalBlue},
style strands={9}{RoyalBlue}] 
(braid) 
s_3 s_2 s_1 s_4 s_3 s_2
s_6 s_7 s_8 
s_5 s_4 s_3 s_6 s_5 s_4 s_7 s_6 s_5
s_5 s_4 s_3 s_6 s_5 s_4 s_7 s_6 s_5;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I see. I'm interested in making the diagram appear more natural, e.g. like in the way that I drew it. As it stands, I can't include that drawing in my writing because I think it will make people think the braid in discussion is more complicated braid than it really is. But, I looked at the documentation and couldn't find anything that could do that. For example, I tried reducing the height, but that did some really weird stuff to the diagram.

Comment: Also, I see other authors drawing nice braids, which makes me think they are either (1) drawing it by hand with tikz paths and whatnot or (2) are using alternatives; hence my question. But it seems like you've already answered that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/549289/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{braids}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic[
  braid/.cd,
  every strand/.style={ultra thick},
  strand 1/.style={red},
  strand 2/.style={red},
  strand 3/.style={red},
  strand 4/.style={green},
  strand 5/.style={green},
  strand 6/.style={black},
  strand 7/.style={blue},
  strand 8/.style={blue},
  strand 9/.style={blue},
  control factor=.001,
  nudge factor=.001,
  height=-.8cm
  ]
{braid={%
s_3-s_6
s_2-s_4-s_7
s_1-s_3-s_5-s_8
s_2-s_4-s_6
s_3-s_5-s_7
s_4-s_6
s_5
s_5
s_4-s_6
s_3-s_5-s_7
s_4-s_6-s_8
s_5-s_7
s_6
}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: complicated braid]

If you reach the limitations of the braids package, try the knots package.

Comment: I already tried, the knots package is depreciated ;) But thanks for the help.

Comment: Since when was the knots package depreciated?

Comment: Oh I was just making a joke about TikZ packages lol. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Oh. I don't get the joke, but not to worry.