# Drawing a CNN with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, draw

For a report I need to draw the architecture of a convolutional neural network (like in the picture). I'm not sure whether drawing it with Tikz would be the best solution, does anyone have any suggestions on how I could do it?

[image: From a paper I'm citing]

Edit: I have already used this code for my report:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[   cnode/.style={draw=black,fill=#1,minimum width=3mm,circle},
]
\node[cnode=black,fill=white,label=0:$\rightarrow$ Output] (s) at (6,-3) {};
\node at (0,-4) {$\vdots$};
\node at (3,-4) {$\vdots$};
\foreach \x in {1,...,4}
    {   \pgfmathparse{\x<4 ? \x : "n"}
    \node[cnode=black,fill=white,label=180:Input $\rightarrow x_{\pgfmathresult}$] (x-\x) at (0,{-\x-\intcalcDiv{\x}{4}}) {};
         \node[cnode=black,fill=white,label=90:$z_{\pgfmathresult}$] (p-\x) at 
    (3,{-\x-\intcalcDiv{\x}{4}}) {};
        \draw (p-\x) -- node[above,sloped,pos=0.3] {\footnotesize 
$\sigma(z_{\pgfmathresult})$} (s);
    }
    \foreach \x in {1,...,4}
    {   \foreach \y in {1,...,4}
        {   \draw (x-\x) -- (p-\y);
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which results in 
[image: fc]

Maybe I could modify that somehow?

Comment: That is an easy enough drawing. What have you done so far? This website is not a "do it for me", so I suggest you look at some TikZ examples, for example here: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/ You may also want to consult the comprehensive TikZ manual at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf It contains a number of tutorials that walk you through the creation of a drawing. In particular, the second and fourth examples (Petri-Net for Hagen, Calculation flowchart) with be helpful.

Comment: Do you really have to draw every 3d detail? If it is for a report it could be a good idea to keep it more simple. Anyway, TikZ is definitely able to draw this (if it's best is opinion-based), but it would be easier for us to help you if we had a minimal code example of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK, seems like you can draw the right part yourself. Here is proposal for a starting point for the left part. (**EDIT**: Added a few more libraries and details. However, I was not able to marry `text effects along path` with `fit text to path`.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,decorations.text,shapes.arrows,positioning,fit,backgrounds}
\tikzset{pics/fake box/.style args={% #1=color, #2=x dimension, #3=y dimension, #4=z dimension
#1 with dimensions #2 and #3 and #4}{
code={
\draw[gray,ultra thin,fill=#1]  (0,0,0) coordinate(-front-bottom-left) to
++ (0,#3,0) coordinate(-front-top-right) --++
(#2,0,0) coordinate(-front-top-right) --++ (0,-#3,0) 
coordinate(-front-bottom-right) -- cycle;
\draw[gray,ultra thin,fill=#1] (0,#3,0)  --++ 
 (0,0,#4) coordinate(-back-top-left) --++ (#2,0,0) 
 coordinate(-back-top-right) --++ (0,0,-#4)  -- cycle;
\draw[gray,ultra thin,fill=#1!80!black] (#2,0,0) --++ (0,0,#4) coordinate(-back-bottom-right)
--++ (0,#3,0) --++ (0,0,-#4) -- cycle;
\path[gray,decorate,decoration={text effects along path,text={CONV}}] (#2/2,{2+(#3-2)/2},0) -- (#2/2,0,0);
}
}}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52856/121799
\tikzset{circle dotted/.style={dash pattern=on .05mm off 2mm,
                                         line cap=round}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1,0)},y={(0,1)},z={({cos(60)},{sin(60)})},
font=\sffamily\small,scale=2]
%
% comment these out if you want to see where the axes point to
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[below]{$x$};
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[left]{$y$};
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[below]{$z$};
% a plane
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {1.6,1.4,1.2,1.2,1}
{
\draw pic (box1-\Y) at (\Y,-\X/2,0) {fake box=white!70!gray with dimensions 0.5 and {2*\X} and 1*\X};
}

\foreach \X/\Col in {6.5/red,6.7/green,6.9/blue}
{\draw[canvas is yz plane at x = \X, transform shape, draw = red, fill =
\Col!50!white, opacity = 0.5] (0,0.5) rectangle (2,-1.5);}
\draw[gray!60,thick] (6.3,-0.1,-1.6) coordinate (1-1) -- (6.3,-0.1,0.6) coordinate (1-2) -- (6.3,2.,0.6) coordinate (1-3) -- (6.3,2.1,-1.6) coordinate (1-4) -- cycle;
\draw[gray!60,thick] (7.1,-0.1,-1.6) coordinate (2-1) -- (7.1,-0.1,0.6) coordinate (2-2) -- (7.1,2.,0.6) coordinate (2-3) -- (7.1,2.1,-1.6) coordinate (2-4) -- cycle;
\foreach \X in {4,1,3}
{\draw[gray!60,thick] (1-\X) -- (2-\X);}
%
\node[draw,single arrow, orange,fill=orange!30] at (8,0.5,0) {GAP};
\node[circle,draw,blue,fill=blue!30] (A1) at (9,1,0) {~~~};
\node[circle,draw,red,fill=red!30,below=4pt of A1] (A2) {~~~};
\node[circle,draw,green,fill=green!30,below=18pt of A2] (A3) {~~~};
\draw[circle dotted, line width=2pt,shorten <=3pt] (A2) -- (A3);
\node[circle,draw,gray,fill=gray!20] (B1) at (10,1,0) {~~~};
\node[circle,draw,fill=gray!60,below=4pt of B1] (B2) {~~~};
\node[circle,draw,gray,fill=gray!20,below=18pt of B2] (B3) {~~~};
\draw[circle dotted, line width=2pt,shorten <=3pt] (B2) -- (B3);
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\node[orange,thick,rounded corners,fill=orange!30,fit=(A1) (A3)]{};
\node[gray,thick,rounded corners,fill=gray!10,fit=(B1) (B3)]{};
\end{scope}
\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
{\draw[-latex] (A\X) -- (B2);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want to draw a CNN-related network with latex but feel overwhelmed with the 1000-page material to learn on latex, PGF, and Tiks, I would suggest you first visit [PlotNeuralNet in Github](https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet) and learn from some examples there. In addition to the example latex files, the project contains some python files to automate the code editing.