# Place Value Chart in Matrix Environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I want to add another columns (yellow) for the Millions Place plus I would like to auto adjust textwidth and height of the nodes while reading the place values from bottom up:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{aqua}{rgb}{0.0, 1.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{carnationpink}{rgb}{1.0, 0.65, 0.79}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,draw,
   row 1/.style={nodes={rotate=90,anchor=west,font=\bfseries}}] (mat)
   {|[text=blue]| \Large Millions &\Large Hundred Thousands & \Large Ten Thousands 
    & |[text=blue]| \Large Thousands & \Large hundreds & \Large tens & | 
      [text=blue]| \Large ones\\
       |[text width=8mm,align=center]| \Large & |[text 
    width=8mm,align=center]| \Large 
    & |[text width=8mm,align=center]| \Large &|[text 
          width=8mm,align=center]| \Large  
    & |[text width=8mm,align=center]|\Large 3 & |[text 
      width=8mm,align=center]| 
      \Large 6 & |[text width=8mm,align=center]| \Large $\mathbf{4}$ \\
     };
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2,...,7}
 {\path (mat-1-\Y.center) -- (mat-1-\X.center) coordinate[midway] (h-\Y);
 \draw (h-\Y|-mat.south) -- (h-\Y|-mat.north);}
 \draw (mat-2-7.north -|mat.west) -- (mat-2-7.north -|mat.east);
 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
 \fill[yellow] (h-2|-mat.south) rectangle (mat.north east);
\fill[carnationpink] (h-4|-mat.south) rectangle (mat.north west); 
\fill[aqua] (h-4|-mat.south) rectangle (mat.north east);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{aqua}{rgb}{0.0, 1.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{carnationpink}{rgb}{1.0, 0.65, 0.79}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,draw,column sep=0.4em,
 row 1/.style={nodes={rotate=90,anchor=west,font=\bfseries}}] (mat)
{
|[text=blue]| Millions & Hundred Thousands & Ten Thousands & |[text=blue]| Thousands & hundreds & tens & |[text=blue]| ones\\
 & &  &  & 3 & 6 & 4 \\
  };
  \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2,...,7}
  {\path (mat-1-\Y.center) -- (mat-1-\X.center) coordinate[midway] (h-\Y);
  \draw (h-\Y|-mat.south) -- (h-\Y|-mat.north);}
  \draw (mat-2-7.north -|mat.west) -- (mat-2-7.north -|mat.east);
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
   \fill[aqua] (h-4|-mat.south) rectangle (mat.north east); 
   \fill[carnationpink] (h-4|-mat.south) rectangle (h-1|-mat.north east); 
   \fill[yellow] (h-1|-mat.south) rectangle (mat.north west); 
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The matrix strategy is only good for non-tilted texts. So if you want to tilt the texts, you could do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,backgrounds,calc}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{aqua}{rgb}{0.0, 1.0, 1.0}
\definecolor{carnationpink}{rgb}{1.0, 0.65, 0.79}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \edef\LstColors{{"aqua","carnationpink","yellow","green"}}
 \edef\LstPrefixes{{"One","Ten","Hundred"}}
 \edef\LstSuffices{{"s","~Thousands","~Millions","~Billions"}}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\rot}{75} % "tilting" angle
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=mat]
  \foreach \Y [count=\Z] in 
  {0,0,5,4,6,6,3,8,0,~,~,~}
  {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{mod(\Z-1,3)}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\myprefix}{\LstPrefixes[int(mod(\Z-1,3))]}
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysuffix}{\LstSuffices[int((\Z-1)/3)]}
   \ifnum\itest=0
     \node[rotate=\rot,anchor=west,font=\bfseries,text=blue] (t-\Z) 
        at (-\Z*2em,0) {\myprefix\mysuffix};
   \else
     \node[rotate=\rot,anchor=west,font=\bfseries] (t-\Z) 
        at (-\Z*2em,0) {\myprefix\mysuffix};
   \fi
   \path (-1em-\Z*2em,0) coordinate (h-\Z);
   \node[below=0pt of t-\Z.west] (l-\Z) {\Y};
 \xdef\numNodes{\Z}}
 \draw (-1em,0) coordinate (h-0) -- (-1em-\numNodes*2em,0);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[on background layer] 
 \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {0,...,\numexpr\numNodes-1}
   {\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\LstColors[int(\X/3)]}
   \draw[right color=\mycolor,left color=\mycolor!50,shading angle=90+\rot] 
     (h-\X) 
     -- (intersection cs:first line={(h-\X)--($(h-\X)+(\rot:5)$)},
     second line={(mat.north west)--(mat.north east)})
     -- (intersection cs:first line={(h-\Y)--($(h-\Y)+(\rot:5)$)},
     second line={(mat.north west)--(mat.north east)})
     -- (h-\Y) 
     -- cycle;
   \draw[bottom color=\mycolor,top color=\mycolor!30]
    (h-\X|-mat.south) rectangle (h-\Y);
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{mod(\Y,3)}
   \ifnum\itest=0
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysuffix}{\LstSuffices[int((\Y-1)/3)]}
    \ifnum\Y=3
    \def\mysuffix{Ones}
    \fi
    \node[draw,minimum width=6em,anchor=south west,minimum height=2em,
     fill=\mycolor] (t-\Y) at 
     (intersection cs:first line={(h-\Y)--($(h-\Y)+(\rot:5)$)},
     second line={(mat.north west)--(mat.north east)})  {\mysuffix};
   \fi}
   \draw[right color=aqua,left color=aqua!50,shading angle=90+\rot] 
   let \p1=($(l-1.north)-(l-1.south)$) in 
   (intersection cs:first line={(h-0)--($(h-0)+(\rot:5)$)},
     second line={(mat.north west)--(mat.north east)})
     -- ++(0,-\y1) --
     (l-1.south -| h-0) -- (h-0);
   \draw[fill=orange!20] (t-12.north west) -- ++ (0,2em) -| (t-3.north east);
   \path (t-12.north west) + (0,2em) -- (t-3.north east)
   node[midway]{Periods};
   \end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought I tried that , but it appears I don't quite understand the programming. I will try with billions place value (purple). If I have further questions I'll ask later here today

Comment: I have achieved the billions place value. I understand about 50% but still need to look at the manual later. One quick question. Without changing the program too much can one slant the worded text (and hence the rectangles into parallelograms) while leaving the number as they are?

Comment: I think rotate may distort it?

Comment: yes I meant the boundaries so one does not have to tilt their head too much-- the rectangles would have to be parallelograms

Comment: it looks fantastic!

Comment: I added an image of the tilted. This image and yours has a 3D look. If you could throw on the few more attributes, that would be great(not all just the important few) . I found on p. 905 in the current manual the foreach\count  option which I have never seen before. I didn't think this image would be as difficult as this. Easy for you, impossible for me.

Comment: @MathScholar Do you want the texts rotated as in your screen shot or projected texts like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473686/121799)? (I am now busy but can give it a shot later. Of course, you could also ask a new question for this because then you will most likely get several answers, and others will have a better chance seeing Q & A, i.e. the 3d features are not really part of the original question.)

Comment: That is really cool!!!. Just like the screenshot and only when you have time. Please no hurry. I am starting to study the manual . I would like to bring my skills to a better level and that requires time and study

Comment: @MathScholar OK, I added something. (It is IMHO now much simpler since all you need to input are the digits.)

Comment: absolutely fantastic!!