# Drawing 3D convolutional neural network block with TiKZ/TeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d

I'd like to draw a 3D volume of blocks for representing convolutional network (CNN) using Ti*k*Z. Below is a picture I'm trying to re-create:

[image: 3D CNN]

I've been struggling to create this block for days and still not much progress :(. Could the Ti*k*Z ninjas here help me with this?

Please note that the horizontal line below the second slab is not needed (it appeared while cropping). Thanks!

Below is what I tried so far (based on the solution of [Drawing a CNN with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439173/100564))

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,decorations.text,shapes.arrows,positioning,fit,backgrounds}
\tikzset{pics/fake box/.style args={% #1=color, #2=x dimension, #3=y dimension, #4=z dimension
#1 with dimensions #2 and #3 and #4}{
code={
\draw[gray,ultra thin,fill=#1]  (0,0,0) coordinate(-front-bottom-left) to
++ (0,#3,0) coordinate(-front-top-right) --++
(#2,0,0) coordinate(-front-top-right) --++ (0,-#3,0) 
coordinate(-front-bottom-right) -- cycle;
\draw[gray,ultra thin,fill=#1] (0,#3,0)  --++ 
 (0,0,#4) coordinate(-back-top-left) --++ (#2,0,0) 
 coordinate(-back-top-right) --++ (0,0,-#4)  -- cycle;
\draw[gray,ultra thin,fill=#1!80!black] (#2,0,0) --++ (0,0,#4) coordinate(-back-bottom-right)
--++ (0,#3,0) --++ (0,0,-#4) -- cycle;
\path[gray,decorate,decoration={text effects along path,text={CONV}}] (#2/2,{2+(#3-2)/2},0) -- (#2/2,0,0);
}
}}
\tikzset{circle dotted/.style={dash pattern=on .05mm off 2mm,
                                         line cap=round}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1,0)},y={(0,1)},z={({cos(60)},{sin(60)})},
font=\sffamily\small,scale=2]
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {1.6,1.4,1.2,1.2,1}
{
\draw pic (box1-\Y) at (\Y,-\X/2,0) {fake box=white!70!gray with dimensions 0.5 and {2*\X} and 1*\X};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

With the above code, I can get the below figure:

[image: cnn spaced out]

---

However, I don't want text on all the blocks but just on the first block only (as can be seen in the orange figure). I would like to adapt the code to produce the orange figure.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439170/drawing-a-cnn-with-tikz

Comment: @samcarter Thanks! Incidentally, that's the code I'm trying to adapt to create the above figure but still couldn't get it right.

Comment: Can you show use what you tried to adapt it and which problems you face?

Comment: @samcarter Please see the code and figure in the updated question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,decorations.text,shapes.arrows,positioning,fit,backgrounds}
\tikzset{pics/fake box/.style args={% #1=color, #2=x dimension, #3=y dimension, #4=z dimension
#1 with dimensions #2 and #3 and #4}{
code={
\draw[ultra thin,fill=#1]  (0,0,0) coordinate(-front-bottom-left) to
++ (0,#3,0) coordinate(-front-top-right) --++
(#2,0,0) coordinate(-front-top-right) --++ (0,-#3,0) 
coordinate(-front-bottom-right) -- cycle;
\draw[ultra thin,fill=#1] (0,#3,0)  --++ 
 (0,0,#4) coordinate(-back-top-left) --++ (#2,0,0) 
 coordinate(-back-top-right) --++ (0,0,-#4)  -- cycle;
\draw[ultra thin,fill=#1!80!black] (#2,0,0) --++ (0,0,#4) coordinate(-back-bottom-right)
--++ (0,#3,0) --++ (0,0,-#4) -- cycle;
\path[decorate,decoration={text effects along path,text={CONV}}] (#2/2,{2+(#3-2)/2},0) -- (#2/2,0,0);
}
}}
\tikzset{pics/empty fake box/.style args={% #1=color, #2=x dimension, #3=y dimension, #4=z dimension
#1 with dimensions #2 and #3 and #4}{
code={
\draw[ultra thin,fill=#1]  (0,0,0) coordinate(-front-bottom-left) to
++ (0,#3,0) coordinate(-front-top-right) --++
(#2,0,0) coordinate(-front-top-right) --++ (0,-#3,0) 
coordinate(-front-bottom-right) -- cycle;
\draw[ultra thin,fill=#1] (0,#3,0)  --++ 
 (0,0,#4) coordinate(-back-top-left) --++ (#2,0,0) 
 coordinate(-back-top-right) --++ (0,0,-#4)  -- cycle;
\draw[ultra thin,fill=#1!80!black] (#2,0,0) --++ (0,0,#4) coordinate(-back-bottom-right)
--++ (0,#3,0) --++ (0,0,-#4) -- cycle;
}
}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(1,0)},y={(0,1)},z={({cos(60)},{sin(60)})},
font=\sffamily\small,scale=2]
%
% comment these out if you want to see where the axes point to
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[below]{$x$};
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[left]{$y$};
% \draw[-latex] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[below]{$z$};
% a plane
\foreach \X/\Y [count=\Z] in {0/0.8,0.4/0.6,0.7/0.4,0.9/0.2,1.0/0.2}
{\ifnum\Z=1
\draw pic (box1-\Z) at (\X,-\Y,-\Y/2) 
{fake box=orange!90!black with dimensions {\Y} and {4*\Y} and 2*\Y};
\else
\draw pic (box1-\Z) at (\X,-\Y,-\Y/2) 
{empty fake box=orange!90!black with dimensions {\Y} and {4*\Y} and 2*\Y};
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Few more requirements: black borderlines, and no space between the last slab and the previous one :)

Comment: @kmario23 Done. (If you want something that is gray to become black, you may just replace `gray` by `black` in the corresponding path.)