# how fit a big tree in the paper and change the place of some nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees

I made this tree by the following code

[image]

```
    \begin{forest}
  for tree={
    rounded corners,
    draw,
    align=center,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!20,
  },
  forked edges,
  [a
    [$ q_{1}k_{1} $
    [$ q_{2}k_{2} $
    [$ q_{3}k_{3} $]
    [$ \cdots $]
    [$ q_{3}k_{3} +(k_{3}-1)$]]
    [$ \cdots $]
    [$ q_{2}k_{2} +(k_{2}-1)$
        [$ q_{3}k_{3} $]
    [$ \cdots $]
    [$ q_{3}k_{3} +(k_{3}-1)$]
    ]]
    [$ \cdots $]
    [$ q_{1}k_{1} +(k_{1}-1)$
    [$ q_{2}k_{2} $
    [$ q_{3}k_{3} $]
    [$ \cdots $]
    [$ q_{3}k_{3} +(k_{3}-1)$]]
    [$ \cdots $]
    [$ q_{2}k_{2} +(k_{2}-1)$
[$ q_{3}k_{3} $]
    [$ \cdots $]
    [$ q_{3}k_{3} +(k_{3}-1)$]]    
    ]]

\end{forest}
```

I have 2 problem

1- the tree is not fitted in my paper.

2- how I can bring boxes with ... into middle?

Comment: Thanks for the update! But in order to know whether or not the tree fits into the paper, one will need a complete document that starts with `\documentclass` so that it is clear how wide the page is. Given what I see here I feel that it is quite likely that you will need landscape mode.

Comment: its \documentclass[12pt]{unbthesis}

Comment: Rather than putting the document class into a comment you should edit the question *so that* the provided code is a complete [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). That is, the should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier to help you because we can reproduce your actual problem.

Comment: In addition to what @Andrew is saying, you may want to provide us with a link of `unbthesis.cls` which does not seem to be a class that ships with the standard TeX distributions (but I may be wrong).

Comment: could we substitute `q1k1` with (say) `p1` --this would reduce the space taken up-- similar action for the `k2-1` could be replaced with `-1`--and the `cdots` could be vertical instead of horizontal

Answer (score 2):

One way is to rotate diagram for 90 degree:

[image]

(red lines indicate text borders)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
   \begin{forest}
  for tree={
    grow'=0,
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    minimum height=3.4ex, inner sep=3pt,
    top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!20,
    anchor=west,
%
    math content,
% edges
  forked edge,
  s sep=2mm,
  l sep=8mm,
fork sep=4mm,
  }
%
[a
    [q_{1}k_{1}
        [q_{2}k_{2}
            [q_{3}k_{3}]
            [\cdots]
            [q_{3}k_{3} +(k_{3}-1)]
        ]
        [\cdots]
        [q_{2}k_{2} +(k_{2}-1)
            [q_{3}k_{3}]
            [\cdots]
            [q_{3}k_{3} +(k_{3}-1)]
        ]
    ]
    [\cdots]
    [q_{1}k_{1} +(k_{1}-1) 
        [q_{2}k_{2}
            [q_{3}k_{3}]
            [\cdots]
            [q_{3}k_{3} +(k_{3}-1)]
        ]
        [\cdots]
        [q_{2}k_{2} +(k_{2}-1) 
            [q_{3}k_{3}]
            [\cdots]
            [q_{3}k_{3} +(k_{3}-1)]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```