# How to add a legend without use pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

i'm using TikZ to recreate several graphics as a practice (and because i'm bored). I draw this graph but i need to add a legend for the dotted line (green) and the normal one (black). How can i do that without using PGF Plots? That restriction is only for a personal challenge bc in differents answers here in this site i've found that everyone uses that.
I'm just starting to use the TikZ library, i'm a completely noob. Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [<->] (0,4) -- (0,0) -- (4,0);
\draw [dotted, ultra thick, color=darkpastelgreen] (0,3) -- (3,0);
\draw [-] (0,3) -- (3,0);
\node [left] at (0,3) {$100$};
\node [below] at (3,0) {$100$};
\node [below left] at (0,0) {0};
\node [below] at (4,0) {$S_{B}$};
\node [left] at (0,4) {$S_{A}$};
\draw [dashed, color=lightgray] (0,3) -- (3,3) -- (3,0);
\draw[decoration={brace,raise=5pt},decorate]
  (0,2.9) -- node[above right=6pt] {Agreement Zone} (2.9,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

And i want something like this:
[image]

Last question: is my code optimal? or I could do it in a more optimal way? I appreciate all kinds of help to improve my graphs.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54794/using-a-pgfplots-style-legend-in-a-plain-old-tikzpicture

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome! Adding a legend is rather easy. All you need is a `matrix` and a `pic`,

```
\path (current bounding box.north east) 
 node[matrix,anchor=north east,draw,nodes={anchor=center},inner sep=2pt]  {
  \pic{sample=black}; & \node{$BR_A$}; \\
  \pic{sample={Dotted,ultra thick,color=darkpastelgreen}}; & \node{$BR_B$}; \\
 };
```

Here, the `pic` sample was defined to feature the style of the plot you use in your picture. One could make it more automatic but this would merely mean switching to `pgfplots`, which you do not seem to want. One may improve your code in many ways, but this requires more input from your side. A rather obvious way of improving it is to use the nice dotted line from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52856/194703).
Anyway, here is a somewhat more ergonomic code that is closer to your target picture. It avoids duplication of coordinates (to some extent) and uses `-|` and similar tricks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\definecolor{darkpastelgreen}{RGB}{105,186,72}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,scale=pi/2,
    pics/sample/.style={code={\draw[#1] (0,0) --(0.6,0) ;}},
    Dotted/.style={% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52856/194703
    dash pattern=on 0.1\pgflinewidth off #1\pgflinewidth,line cap=round,
    shorten >=#1\pgflinewidth/2,shorten <=#1\pgflinewidth/2},
    Dotted/.default=3]
\draw [<->] (0,4) node[left] {$S_{A}$} -- (0,0) node[below left]  {$0$}
-- (4,0) node [below] {$S_{B}$};
\draw [-] (0,3)node[left]  {$100$}  -- (3,0) node[below]  {$100$};
\draw [Dotted,ultra thick, color=darkpastelgreen] (0,3)-- (3,0);
\draw [dashed, color=lightgray] (0,3) -| (3,0);
\draw[decoration={brace,raise=5pt},decorate,thick]
  (0,2.9) -- node[above right=2ex,xshift=-2ex,align=left] {Agreement\\ Zone} (2.9,0);
\path (current bounding box.north east) 
 node[matrix,anchor=north east,draw,nodes={anchor=center},inner sep=2pt]  {
  \pic{sample=black}; & \node{$BR_A$}; \\
  \pic{sample={Dotted,ultra thick,color=darkpastelgreen}}; & \node{$BR_B$}; \\
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is my suggestion. Instead of `pgfplots`, I use TikZ only: putting `pic` (name `circ` is a small colored circle) along `path`.

An other way is using decoration along path.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,
circ/.pic={\fill[green!50!black] (0,0) circle(1.5pt);}]
\draw (0,3)--(3,0);
\draw[<->] (0,4)--(0,0)--(5,0);
\draw[dashed,lightgray] (0,3)-|(3,0);
\draw[decoration={brace,raise=3pt},decorate]
    (0,3)--(3,0);
\foreach \i in {0,.05,...,1.05}
\path (0,3)--(3,0) pic[pos=\i]{circ};

\path
(0,3) node[left]{$100$}
(3,0) node[below]{$100$}
(0,0) node[below left]{0}
(5,0) node[below]{$S_{B}$}
(0,4) node[left]{$S_{A}$}
(2.2,2.2) node[align=left,scale=.8] {Agreement\\Zone};

% for legend
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=L,shift={(4.5,3.5)}]
\path (0,0) node (A) {$BR_A$}
(-90:.4) node (B) {$BR_B$};
\draw (A.west)--+(180:.6);
\foreach \i in {0,.3,...,1}
\path (B.west)--+(180:.6) pic[pos=\i]{circ};
\end{scope} 
\draw ([xshift=-2mm]L.south west) rectangle (L.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```