# Communication flow between server and client with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

i would represent the communication flow between a client and a server by using Tikz.
The communication flow is reported in the image.

[image: Communication flow]

Based on this, i started to use Tikz to design this flow in my work. The current code is:

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,auto,>=stealth']
\node[] (server) {Server};
\node[left = of server] (client) {Client};
\node[below of=server, node distance=5cm] (server_ground) {};
\node[below of=client, node distance=5cm] (client_ground) {};
%
\draw (client) -- (client_ground);
\draw (server) -- (server_ground);
\draw[->] ($(client)!0.25!(client_ground)$) -- node[above,scale=1,midway]{m_1} ($(server)!0.25!(server_ground)$);
\draw[<-] ($(client)!0.35!(client_ground)$) -- node[above,scale=1,midway]{Response m_1} ($(server)!0.35!(server_ground)$);
\draw[->] ($(client)!0.45!(client_ground)$) -- node[above,scale=1,midway]{m2} ($(server)!0.45!(server_ground)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But i'm not able to design the dot below m2 and m3 and also the line on the right related to the Time.

Can you help me please?

Bestregards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! Instead of all these coordinate computations I would set up a local coordinate system in which `(0,0)` is the the `(client_ground)` coordinate and `(1,1)` is the tip of the arrow pointing to `server`. Other than that I'd use `positioning` and `arrows.meta`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{85,114,193}
\tikzset{Dotted/.style={% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52856/194703
    line width=1pt,
    dash pattern=on 0.01\pgflinewidth off #1\pgflinewidth,line cap=round,
    shorten >=0.3em,shorten <=0.3em},
    Dotted/.default=5}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=Triangle,font=\sffamily]
\node (server) {Server};
\node[base left=4cm  of server] (client) {Client};
\coordinate[below=6cm of server] (server_ground);
\coordinate[below=6cm of client] (client_ground);
%
\draw[line width=2pt,myblue] (client) -- (client_ground)
 (server) -- (server_ground);
\begin{scope}[line width=3pt,draw=myblue,shift={(client_ground)},
    nodes={above},declare function={t1=0.85;r1=0.6;t2=0.45;t3=0.1;},
    x={($(server_ground)-(client_ground)$)},y={($(client.south)-(client_ground)$)}]
 \draw[->] (0,t1) -- node{$m_1$} (1,t1);
 \draw[->] (1,r1) -- node{response $m_1$} (0,r1);
 \draw[->] (0,t2) -- node(m2){$m_2$}  (1,t2);
 \draw[->] (0,t3) -- node(m3) {$m_3$}  (1,t3);
 \draw[-,Dotted=8,line width=4pt, shorten <=5pt] (m2) -- (m3);
 \draw[semithick,<->] (1.1,t3) -- (1.1,t2) node[midway,right]{Time};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what i searched.