# Algorithm flow chart in tikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, algorithms, flow-charts

The flow chart below consists of blocks, representing data and functions, that run clockwise, while outside this series of blocks are explanatory steps. how would you code this in LaTeX while making the text both in the blocks and the surrounding steps editable? is Tikz the way to go? For use as a figure in a research article.

[image]

Comment: Please do not expect others to punch in all the texts from a screen shot. Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: to be honest, i'm completely new to tikz and have doubts it can even handle this challenge

Comment: It certainly can but probably not many want to punch in everything for you.

Comment: don't worry about punching everything. the placement of boxes, arrows, dots and the surrounding texts is what im worried about

Comment: I guess no one worries about a lot of text from screenshot. Without MWE showing what you have tried so far, simply you get low chance to be helped.

Comment: I do not know what you want to achieve by accepting an answer and unaccepting it considerable time later, but I can assure you that I am not excited about such games.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The layout is easy, punching in texts is cumbersome. So I added a lot of bla bla. You only need matrices and some styles for hatching etc. To add the surrounding texts, put the diagram in a `local bounding box` and use the vertical or horizontal positions of the nodes for the placement of the texts.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,matrix,patterns.meta,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node font=\sffamily,>=Triangle,
    Dotted/.style={% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52856/194703
    line width=1.2pt,
    dash pattern=on 0.01\pgflinewidth off #1\pgflinewidth,line cap=round,
    shorten >=0.5em,shorten <=0.5em},
    Dotted/.default=6,
    mmat/.style={matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,nodes={minimum width=3em,
            draw,anchor=center,
            text depth=0.25ex,text height=0.8em}},
    dotcell/.style={minimum height=4em,path picture={
        \draw[Dotted] (path picture bounding box.north)--
        (path picture bounding box.south);}},
    hatchcell/.style={pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={3pt}]}},
    vcell/.style={xshift=-1ex,hatchcell},
    block/.style={draw,align=center}    
    ]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=diagram]
  \node[mmat] (vmat1) {|[vcell]|1 \\
     2 \\ |[dotcell]|\\  10\\ }; 
  %
  \node[mmat,below=2em of vmat1] (vmat2) {1 \\
     |[vcell]| 2 \\ |[dotcell]|\\  10\\ };   
  %
  \node[mmat,below=3em of vmat2] (vmat3) {1 \\
     2 \\ |[dotcell]|\\  |[vcell]|  10\\ };  
  %  
  \foreach \X in {1,2,3}
  {\node[right=3em of vmat\X,block](b\X){regression\textsubscript{a}\\
     regression\textsubscript{b}\\ regression\textsubscript{c}};
  \draw[->] (vmat\X-3-1.east|-b\X) -- (b\X);}
  %
  \node[right=3em of b1.south east,anchor=south west,mmat,
     column 1/.style={nodes={hatchcell}}] (hmat1) {
   1 & $Z_{1\mathsf{a}}$ & $Z_{1\mathsf{b}}$ & $Z_{1\mathsf{c}}$ \\
   2 & $Z_{2\mathsf{a}}$ & $Z_{2\mathsf{b}}$ & $Z_{2\mathsf{c}}$ \\
  }; 
  \draw[->] (b1.east|-hmat1-1-1.west) -- (hmat1-1-1.west);
  %
  \node[right=3em of b2.north east,anchor=north west,mmat,
     column 1/.style={nodes={hatchcell}}] (hmat2) {
   10 & $Z_{10\mathsf{a}}$ & $Z_{10\mathsf{b}}$ & $Z_{10\mathsf{c}}$ \\
  }; 
  \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {a,b,c}
  {\node[below=\Y*2em of hmat2-1-\the\numexpr\Y+1\relax,block] 
     (CV\Y) {CV Risk\textsubscript{\X}};
  \draw[->] (hmat2-1-\the\numexpr\Y+1\relax) -- (CV\Y); }
  \draw (CV1.west) -- ++ (-1ex,0) |- (CV3);
  \draw[->] (b2.east) -- ++(1em,0) |- (hmat1-2-1.west);
  \draw[->] (b3.east) -- ++(2em,0) |- (hmat2-1-1.west);
  %
  \node[block,below=12em of hmat2](F){Family of weighted\\
     combinations}; 
  \draw[->] (CV2.south-|F) -- (F);
  %
  \node[block,below=4em of F.south west,xshift=-3em] (P)
  {Some long formula with P}; 
  \draw[<-] (P.east) -- ++ (1em,0) coordinate (aux) -- (F.south-|aux);
  \node[block,left=3em of P,text width=8em] (PP)  {\vphantom{P}}; 
  \draw[->] (P) -- (PP);
  %
  \node[left=3em of vmat2.north west,block] (A){Collection of\\ algorithms}; 
  \node[left=3em of vmat2.south west,block] (MD){Mortality\\ data};  
  \draw[->] (A.east) -- ++ (1.2em,0) |- (vmat1-3-1);
  \draw[->] (A.east) -- ++ (1.2em,0) |- (vmat3-3-1);
  \draw[->] (MD.east) -- ++ (1.2em,0) |- (vmat2-3-1);
  \path (current bounding box.south west) + (-1ex,-1ex)
  (current bounding box.north east) + (1ex,1ex);
 \end{scope} 
 \node[text width=7em,above] at (MD|-diagram.north){1.\ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla};
 \node[text width=7em,above] at (vmat1|-diagram.north){2.\ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla};
 \node[text width=7em,above] at (b1|-diagram.north){3.\ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla};
 \node[text width=12em,above] at (hmat1|-diagram.north){4.\ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla};
 \node[text width=8em,right] at (hmat2-|diagram.east){5.\ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla};
 \node[text width=8em,right] at (F-|diagram.east){6.\ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla};
 \node[text width=9em,below] at (P|-diagram.south){7.\ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla};
 \node[text width=9em,below] at (PP|-diagram.south){8.\ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a version that works on (some of the) outdated TeX installations.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,matrix,patterns,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node font=\sffamily,>=Triangle,
    Dotted/.style={% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52856/194703
    line width=1.2pt,
    dash pattern=on 0.01\pgflinewidth off #1\pgflinewidth,line cap=round,
    shorten >=0.5em,shorten <=0.5em},
    Dotted/.default=6,
    mmat/.style={matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,nodes={minimum width=3em,
            draw,anchor=center,
            text depth=0.25ex,text height=0.8em}},
    dotcell/.style={minimum height=4em,path picture={
        \draw[Dotted] (path picture bounding box.north)--
        (path picture bounding box.south);}},
    hatchcell/.style={pattern=north east lines},
    vcell/.style={xshift=-1ex,hatchcell},
    block/.style={draw,align=center}    
    ]
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=diagram]
  \node[mmat] (vmat1) {|[vcell]|1 \\
     2 \\ |[dotcell]|\\  10\\ }; 
  %
  \node[mmat,below=2em of vmat1] (vmat2) {1 \\
     |[vcell]| 2 \\ |[dotcell]|\\  10\\ };   
  %
  \node[mmat,below=3em of vmat2] (vmat3) {1 \\
     2 \\ |[dotcell]|\\  |[vcell]|  10\\ };  
  %  
  \foreach \X in {1,2,3}
  {\node[right=3em of vmat\X,block](b\X){regression\textsubscript{a}\\
     regression\textsubscript{b}\\ regression\textsubscript{c}};
  \draw[->] (vmat\X-3-1.east|-b\X) -- (b\X);}
  %
  \node[right=3em of b1.south east,anchor=south west,mmat,
     column 1/.style={nodes={hatchcell}}] (hmat1) {
   1 & $Z_{1\mathsf{a}}$ & $Z_{1\mathsf{b}}$ & $Z_{1\mathsf{c}}$ \\
   2 & $Z_{2\mathsf{a}}$ & $Z_{2\mathsf{b}}$ & $Z_{2\mathsf{c}}$ \\
  }; 
  \draw[->] (b1.east|-hmat1-1-1.west) -- (hmat1-1-1.west);
  %
  \node[right=3em of b2.north east,anchor=north west,mmat,
     column 1/.style={nodes={hatchcell}}] (hmat2) {
   10 & $Z_{10\mathsf{a}}$ & $Z_{10\mathsf{b}}$ & $Z_{10\mathsf{c}}$ \\
  }; 
  \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {a,b,c}
  {\node[below=\Y*2em of hmat2-1-\the\numexpr\Y+1\relax,block] 
     (CV\Y) {CV Risk\textsubscript{\X}};
  \draw[->] (hmat2-1-\the\numexpr\Y+1\relax) -- (CV\Y); }
  \draw (CV1.west) -- ++ (-1ex,0) |- (CV3);
  \draw[->] (b2.east) -- ++(1em,0) |- (hmat1-2-1.west);
  \draw[->] (b3.east) -- ++(2em,0) |- (hmat2-1-1.west);
  %
  \node[block,below=12em of hmat2](F){Family of weighted\\
     combinations}; 
  \draw[->] (CV2.south-|F) -- (F);
  %
  \node[block,below=4em of F.south west,xshift=-3em] (P)
  {Some long formula with P}; 
  \draw[<-] (P.east) -- ++ (1em,0) coordinate (aux) -- (F.south-|aux);
  \node[block,left=3em of P,text width=8em] (PP)  {\vphantom{P}}; 
  \draw[->] (P) -- (PP);
  %
  \node[left=3em of vmat2.north west,block] (A){Collection of\\ algorithms}; 
  \node[left=3em of vmat2.south west,block] (MD){Mortality\\ data};  
  \draw[->] (A.east) -- ++ (1.2em,0) |- (vmat1-3-1);
  \draw[->] (A.east) -- ++ (1.2em,0) |- (vmat3-3-1);
  \draw[->] (MD.east) -- ++ (1.2em,0) |- (vmat2-3-1);
  \path (current bounding box.south west) + (-1ex,-1ex)
  (current bounding box.north east) + (1ex,1ex);
 \end{scope} 
 \node[text width=7em,above] at (MD|-diagram.north){1.\ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla};
 \node[text width=7em,above] at (vmat1|-diagram.north){2.\ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla};
 \node[text width=7em,above] at (b1|-diagram.north){3.\ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla};
 \node[text width=12em,above] at (hmat1|-diagram.north){4.\ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla};
 \node[text width=8em,right] at (hmat2-|diagram.east){5.\ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla};
 \node[text width=8em,right] at (F-|diagram.east){6.\ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla};
 \node[text width=9em,below] at (P|-diagram.south){7.\ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla};
 \node[text width=9em,below] at (PP|-diagram.south){8.\ bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
 bla bla};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the code runs into several errors when compiling:  Package pgf Error: Undefined pattern `Lines'. \node[mmat] (vmat1) {|[vcell]|1 \\

Comment: @develarist That's because you have an old TeX installation. `patterns.meta` has been added only recently. If you cannot update, load `patterns` instead of `patterns.meta` and use `hatchcell/.style={pattern={north east lines}}`.

Comment: i was thinking that and updated everything in the miktex console on my first attempt. there were other errors after this though

Comment: @develarist Sorry, this code compiles fine, at least on an updated TeXLive 2020 installation. I do not have a crystal ball that would tell me what goes wrong, so if you say "there were other errors" this does not help.

Comment: i will let u know when this patterns error is fixed. i see the other errors when I comment out the sources of the patterns error. tikz is updated, and i know that "Lines" is within patterns.meta after consulting similar questions before I complained here, but it says the error is in the package called pgf.

Comment: @develarist Your messages are not helpful, sorry. One can only fix errors (which, I stress again, this code does *not* produce on a reasonably up-to-date installation) only if one sees the precise error messages.

Comment: Package pgf Error: Undefined pattern `Lines'. \node[mmat] (vmat1) {|[vcell]|1 \\ ....  Package pgf Error: No shape named MD is known. ...xt width=7em,above] at (MD|-diagram.north) ...

Comment: @develarist I see. You told me that you have fixed the `patterns.meta` related errors but you did not. I added a version that works without `patterns.meta`.

Comment: works now. thanks alot

Comment: Inside this `\foreach \X in {1,2,3}
  {\node[right=3em of vmat\X,block](b\X){regression\textsubscript{a}\\
     regression\textsubscript{b}\\ regression\textsubscript{c}};
  \draw[->] (vmat\X-3-1.east|-b\X) -- (b\X);}` there appears this expression: `(vmat\X-3-1.east|-b\X) -- (b\X)` which after the loop would be written as: `(vmat1-3-1.east|-b1) -- (b1)`  and so on... Does anybody know what the -3-1 before the anchor mean? Also what does the `|` symbol do?