# Block diagram using Tikz picture

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I am trying to generate the following figure using Tikz.[image]

However, I am not able to replicate the arrows.

PS: So far, I have done the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\tikzstyle{sensor}=[draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, 
    text centered, minimum height=2.5em]
\tikzstyle{plant} = [sensor, text width=2em, fill=blue!20, 
    minimum height=5em, rounded corners]   
\tikzstyle{agent} = [sensor, text width=2em, fill=red!10, 
    minimum height=5em, rounded corners]
\tikzstyle{intercon} = [sensor, text width=2em, fill=green!20, 
    minimum height=20em, rounded corners]

\def\PtoI{3}
\def\AtoP{2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (interconn) [intercon] {\rotatebox{270}{$\mu = M Y^d$}};
    \path (interconn.80)+(-\PtoI,0) node (plant1) [plant] {$\Sigma^1$};
    \path (interconn.-80)+(-\PtoI,0) node (plantn) [plant] {$\Sigma^N$};
    \path (plant1.0)+(-\AtoP,0) node (agent1) [agent] {\rotatebox{270}{Agent 1}};
    \path (plantn.0)+(-\AtoP,0) node (agentn) [agent] {\rotatebox{270}{Agent N}};
    \path [draw, <-] (interconn.85) -- node [above] {$\nu$} (plant1.50);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following picture:
[image]

Comment: how about Umlet tool

Comment: @schrodinger Both solutions are accurate and am really thankful. I accepted other because he inserted dots in the middle. I learnt a lot from both of you. Thanks again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `rotate` from Ti*k*Z. This rotates also the anchors but is IMHO still more intuitive than the `\rotatebox`. Then you can add the arrows by using `-|` syntax to take the y coordinate of one node and the x coordinate of the other, and likewise `|-`, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401429/194703) for an explanation. Finally you can avoid repetition with `\foreach`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{fgreen}{RGB}{204,223,181}
\definecolor{dblue}{RGB}{85,113,192}
\definecolor{dgreen}{RGB}{132,171,80}   
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,
sensor/.style={draw, fill=dblue, text width=5em, 
    text centered, minimum height=2.5em},
plant/.style={sensor, text width=2em, fill=dblue, 
    minimum height=5em, rounded corners},   
agent/.style={sensor, minimum width=5em, fill=dgreen, 
    minimum height=2em, rounded corners},
intercon/.style={sensor, minimum width=20em, fill=fgreen, 
    minimum height=2em, rounded corners},
    Dotted/.style={% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52856/194703
    line width=1.2pt,
    dash pattern=on 0.01\pgflinewidth off #1\pgflinewidth,line cap=round,
    shorten >=0.5em,shorten <=0.5em},
    Dotted/.default=6,
    ]
    \def\PtoI{2}
    \def\AtoP{2}
    \node (interconn) [intercon,rotate=-90] {$\mu = M Y^d$};
    \path ([yshift=-3em]interconn.south west)+(-\PtoI,0) node (plant1) [plant] {$\Sigma^1$};
    \path ([yshift=3em]interconn.south east)+(-\PtoI,0) node (plantN) [plant] {$\Sigma^N$};
    \path (plant1.0)+(-\AtoP,0) node (agent1) [agent,rotate=-90]
        {Agent\textsuperscript{1}};
    \path (plantN.0)+(-\AtoP,0) node (agentN) [agent,rotate=-90]
        {Agent\textsuperscript{$N$}};
    \begin{scope}[semithick]
    \foreach \X/\Y/\Z in {1/u/u,N/\nu/a}
     {\draw[->] ([yshift=1em]plant\X.east) -- node[above]{$\bar y^{\X}$}
     ([yshift=1em]plant\X.east-|interconn.south);
     \draw[<-] ([yshift=-1em]plant\X.east) --
      node[below]{$\Y^{\X}$}
     ([yshift=-1em]plant\X.east-|interconn.south);
     \draw[->] (agent\X.west) -- ++ (0,1em) -| 
        node[pos=0.25,above](\Z-\X){$\Z^{\X}$}(plant\X);
     \draw[<-] (agent\X.east) -- ++ (0,-1em) -|  
        node[pos=0.25,below](y-\X){$y^{\X}$}(plant\X);
     }
    \draw[Dotted] (y-1) -- (a-N); 
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Added dotted line (with proper attribution, of course).

Answer (score 6):

With use of relative coordinates and recent syntax for defining nodes styles:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                fit,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    sensor/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=#1, 
                     text width=2em, minimum height=22mm, align=center}, 
     plant/.style = {sensor=blue!20},
     agent/.style = {sensor=red!10},
  intercon/.style = {sensor=green!20, inner ysep=0pt, fit=#1},
                > = {Triangle[angle=60:3pt 2]}
        }

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 32mm and 8mm
                    ]
\node (agent1) [agent] {\rotatebox{90}{Agent$^1$}};
\node (plant1) [plant,right=of agent1] {$\Sigma^1$};
    \draw[->]   (agent1.north) -- ++ (0, 4mm) -| (plant1) 
                node (u1) [pos=0.25,above] {$\nu^1$};
    \draw[->]   (plant1.south) -- ++ (0,-4mm) -| (agent1)
                node (y1) [pos=0.25,below] {$y^1$};
\node (agentN) [agent,below=of agent1] {\rotatebox{90}{Agent$^N$}};
\node (plantN) [plant,right=of agentN] {$\Sigma^N$};
    \draw[->]   (agentN.north) -- ++ (0, 4mm) -| (plantN)
                node (uN) [pos=0.25,above] {$\nu^N$};
    \draw[->]   (plantN.south) -- ++ (0,-4mm) -| (agentN)
                node (yN) [pos=0.25,below] {$y^N$};
\draw[thick,dotted, shorten >=3mm, shorten <=3mm]
    (y1) -- (uN);
%
\coordinate[right=of u1 -| plant1.east] (aux1);
\coordinate[right=of yN -| aux1]        (aux2);
\node (interconn) [intercon=(aux1) (aux2), right,
                   label={[rotate=90]center:$\mu = M Y^d$}] {};
\scoped[transform canvas={yshift=+3mm}]  {
     \draw[->] (plant1) -- node[above] {$\bar{y}^1$} (plant1 -| interconn.west);
     \draw[->] (plantN) -- node[above] {$\bar{y}^N$} (plantN -| interconn.west);
                                        }
\scoped[transform canvas={yshift=-3mm}]  {
     \draw[<-] (plant1) -- node[below] {$\bar{\nu}^1$} (plant1 -| interconn.west);
     \draw[<-] (plantN) -- node[below] {$\bar{\nu}^N$} (plantN -| interconn.west);
                                        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:**
The use of `transform canvas` you need to take a should be used with great care. See warnings in *TikZ & PGF manual*, section 25.4 Canvas Transformations, pp 387 (at version 3.1.5b). Its use in the your case you are on the safe side.

Comment: Both are correct! don't know which one to choose. However, your sol is more accurate.

Comment: @kosa, that is up to you :-) Anyhow how you will decide, you are welcome!

Comment: :) Thanks for the solution. I was struggling with this for quite some time!

Comment: You probably know that you should not use `transform canvas`.

Comment: @kosa Why do you think this one is "more accurate"?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat, if its use not push anything out of bounding box, nothing dangerous happen, so why someone should not use them?

Comment: Precisely because you have to be very careful with this, not only because of the bounding box. Using it without need and without warning will cause problems whenever others try to reuse parts of this code.