# Graph with dotted line

Tags: graphs

[image: graph having a pendent vertices]

How to draw graph as shown in picture using latex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you already an tex code you tried? Please show it us!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: The question is very likely to be closed in the next few hours (if not less). Please remember that you can ask to reopen it if you provide a MWE of what you have tried to do

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! This is a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Dotted/.style={% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52856/194703
    line width=1.5pt,
    dash pattern=on 0.001\pgflinewidth off #1,line cap=round,
    shorten <=#1},Dotted/.default=6pt,
    bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]

  \draw (0,0) -- ++(2,0) node[bullet](X){}
   foreach \X in {60,40,-60} {  (X) ++ (\X:2) node[bullet]{} edge (X)};
  \draw[Dotted] (X) ++ (60:2.2) arc[start angle=60,end angle=-60,radius=2.2]
    node[midway,fill=white]{$a$};

  \draw (0,-4.5) -- ++(2,0) node[bullet](X'){}
   foreach \X in {60,40,-60} {  (X') ++ (\X:2) node[bullet]{} edge (X')};
  \draw[stealth-stealth] (X') ++ (60:2.2) 
  arc[start angle=60,end angle=-60,radius=2.2] node[midway,fill=white]{$a$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the future please try to post some code. Otherwise others have to guess everything, and you will benefit more from the question if you show what you have tried.