# How to make a dotted arrow in a commutative diagram?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I have got the following code for a commutative diagram. I want the arrow from A times X to F times X to be dotted. I would really appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]  
A \times X \arrow{r}{\bar{q}\times 1_x} \arrow[swap]{dr}{q} & F \times X \arrow{d}{\epsilon} \\
 & Y
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\arrow[dotte]{r}{\bar{q}\times 1_x}`?

Comment: It worked, thank you very much

Comment: By any chance do you know how to make the dotted arrow bolder or the dash to be longer so its more visible

Comment: Well, you can use all the `tikz` keys, e.g. `\arrow[dash pattern=on 4pt off 2pt,thick]{r}{\bar{q}\times 1_x}`, or just `dashed`. It would be much easier tottery out if you gave a complete example that starts with `\documentclass` and can be compiled.

Comment: I have now edited the code

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comments (and as has been copied by another user in the mean time) you can add keys like `dotted`. For a thicker and truly dotted line you can use [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52856/), the normal "dots" are just small rectangles. You can also keep the arrow heads small when making the line thicker.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]  
A \times X \arrow[dotted]{r}{\bar{q}\times 1_x} \arrow[swap]{dr}{q} & F \times X \arrow{d}{\epsilon} \\
 & Y
\end{tikzcd}
\qquad
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]  
A \times X \arrow[dash pattern=on 0pt off 3.2pt,line cap=round,line width=0.8pt]{r}{\bar{q}\times 1_x} \arrow[swap]{dr}{q} & F \times X \arrow{d}{\epsilon} \\
 & Y
\end{tikzcd}

\bigskip
\tikzset{thick true dots/.style={dash pattern=on 0pt off pi*#1,
line cap=round,line width=#1},
thick true dots/.default=0.8pt,
oricm/.style={-{cm to[width=1.5ex,length=0.8ex,line width=0.4pt]}}}
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]  
A \times X \arrow[thick true dots]{r}{\bar{q}\times 1_x} \arrow[swap]{dr}{q} & F \times X \arrow{d}{\epsilon} \\
 & Y
\end{tikzcd}
\qquad
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]  
A \times X \arrow[thick true dots=2pt]{r}{\bar{q}\times 1_x} \arrow[swap]{dr}{q} & F \times X \arrow{d}{\epsilon} \\
 & Y
\end{tikzcd}

\bigskip
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]  
A \times X \arrow[oricm,thick true dots]{r}{\bar{q}\times 1_x} \arrow[swap]{dr}{q} & F \times X \arrow{d}{\epsilon} \\
 & Y
\end{tikzcd}
\qquad
\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]  
A \times X \arrow[oricm,thick true dots=2pt]{r}{\bar{q}\times 1_x} \arrow[swap]{dr}{q} & F \times X \arrow{d}{\epsilon} \\
 & Y
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: @Lazy squirrel: If the other user who copied your comments is me, I have the regret to inform you that while you were commenting, I was preparing my answer and screenshot.

Comment: @Bernard I see. And if you had your answer first, and I would just have repeated it (regardless of whether I had prepared it while you posted yours), would that be copying? And if 100 users prepare an answer or comment, there will be 100 answers and comments? To be clear: copying in this context means repeating. If you think that this is a useful exercise then there is nothing that prevents you from doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

 \begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[sep=huge]
A \times X \arrow[dotted]{r}{\bar{q}\times 1_x} \arrow[swap]{dr}{q} & F \times X \arrow{d}{\epsilon} \\
& Y
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*:

To be complete, here is a solution with `pstricks` which gives an easy control of the size of the dotted arrow. Load `pst-node` and use the `psmatrix` environnment:

```
$ \psset{arrowinset=0.15, arrows=->, linejoin=1, nodesep=3pt, labelsep=1pt}
\begin{psmatrix}[colsep=2cm]
  A\times X & F\times X \\
 & Y %
 \ncline[linewidth=1.2pt, linestyle=dotted, dotsep=2pt]{1,1}{1,2}\naput{\bar{q}\times 1_X}%
\ncline{1,1}{2,2}\nbput{q}
\ncline{1,2}{2,2}\naput{\epsilon}
  \end{psmatrix} $
```

[image]

Comment: Hiya, thank you for the help. By any chance do you know how to make the dotted arrow bolder or the dash to be longer so it's more visible.

Comment: @Elise: Unfortunately, I don't know pgf well enough to know how to do that.  For me, the dashed version is acceptable.